# Creating String by using onPressed function

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a User's settings screen with a couple of FlatButtons. I want to use onPressed function to create String when the button is pressed and than pass it further to Settings object and save it on disk.
The problem is - I'm new to Dart/Flutter and completely out of ideas here. I have read the docs about Shared Preferences, Streams, Async etc., but I was unable to find an answer to:
How can I create a String by using onPressed?
Can someone tell me how the code would look like or is it even the right approach to solve it this way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright , you can do it in multiple ways.
Here i created an example for you  copy/paste run it so you can understand .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<String> settings = new List();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            (settings.isEmpty) ?Center(child:Text("no settings found")) :
           ListView.builder(shrinkWrap: true,itemCount: settings.length,itemBuilder: (context,i)
           {
             return  Center(child: Text("${settings[i]}"));
              
           })
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()
        {
          setState(() {
            settings.add('random setting');
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**explanation :**
i created List settings wich has no data at the beginning.
and i check if setting are empty i show empty settings , else it will render the data.
the button with + sign is  adding new strings to the list and will rebuild the widget to show it . with setState({});

hope that helps.